# while(ros :: ok) Dynamic publish

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am beginner in ROS, please excuse me if this question is silly.

I have the below snippet.

```
int main()
{
     //Initialize and start the node
     ros::Publisher pub;
     //Define and create some messages
     abc;
     while(ros : ok)
     {
           ros_time = ros::time::now();
           pub.publish(abc);
           ros::spinOnce();               
     }

 }
```

Now I need to update the abc every 5 ms and publish the updated one. Can anybody please tell me how this could be implemented.

Thank you.
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294951/while(ros-::-ok)-dynamic-publish/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-06-22**:
Hey! Could you maybe first do the tutorials on creating [C++ Publishers](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)? It quite exactly shows you what you need to do.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-22**:
@NEngelhard thank you.. Going through the tutorials..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use `ros::Rate`. See this [Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

EDIT:

Exact code is:

```
 ros::Rate rate(200);
 while(ros::ok())
 {
       //calculate somehow new abc
       abc = new_abc;
       pub.publish(abc);
       loop_rate.sleep();               
 }
```

Thanks @NEngelhard!

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-22**:
Thank you @destogl  ...  Can we update that message every X ms and re-publish to the node ..?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-22**:
Yes, you should just add new value into `abc` variable...

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-22**:
while(ros :: ok)
{
ros_time = ros::time::now();
abc = new_abc;
pub.publish(abc);
ros::spinOnce;

}

@destol Is this the right way of doing it ?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-22**:
Exactly. But if you want to do this every 5ms I would use exact code from my answer.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-23**:
@destogl Thank you, I just implemented that  .. But one doubt, you missed sponOnce ?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-23**:
@kishorkumar No I didn‘t missed it. If you read carefully tutorial explanation, in this case one does not need it.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-23**:
Thank you very much.. I will try implementing the same and update you on Tuesday..

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-26**:
@destogl Thanks for the input, I just implemented it and it worked perfectly fine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-26**:
`ros::ok` is not correct, it should be: `ros::ok()`. At the moment you're probably checking the value of a function pointer (which is always `true`).

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-26**:
Oh. You are right, sorry a typo...

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-26**:
@gvdhoorn Sorry Typo.. Thanks for the help guys..
In relative to this question I am looking for ways to stop the rosrun.. i have already posted a question and updated the code..